# javascript array from shortcode

Tags: javascript, regex, shortcode

I need some help to build an array from a shortcode.
The problem is the match regex part.

my short code looks like this:

```
 [email_image,id=1,c=member,fS=15,lH=20]
```

desired output:

```
{name: 'email_image', id: '1', c: 'member', fS: '15', lH: '20'}
```

How to alter my function `(regex)` to work?

thanks.sepp.

```
function ajax(ed){

        var str = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
        var re = /\[email_image([^\]]*)\]/g;
        var found = str.match(re);

        found.map(function(item){
            //console.log(item);  //  [email_image,id=1,c=member,fS=15,lH=20] ....

            arraytophp = {name: 'email_image', id : item.split(',')[1].split('=')[1], c: item.split(',')[2].split('=')[1], fS : item.split(',')[3].split('=')[1], lH: item.split(',')[4].split('=')[1].replace(']','')};


            // PROBLEM START *************************************************************

            var arraytophp_test = {};
            item.match(/([\w-]+)=([^,]+)/g).forEach(function(attribute) {
                //console.log(attribute)
                attribute = attribute.match(/([\w-]+)=(.+?)/);
                arraytophp_test[attribute[1]] = attribute[2];
            });
            console.log(arraytophp_test);

            // PROBLEM END **************************************************************

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "StringImage_Ajax/ajaxImage",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                data: {"data" : JSON.stringify(arraytophp)}
                }).done(function(data){
                    string = data.string;
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().replace(item,string));    
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Replace `function(attribute)` with `function(match_val, attribute1, attribute2)` and then use `attribute1` instead of `attribute[0]` and `attribute2` instead of `attribute[1]`

Comment: its the regex thats not working as expected. gives me {id: "1", c: "M", fS: "1", lH: "2"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of RegEx, basic javascript can do this nicely.

Of course RegEx is great, but sometime it seems as it's used to smash open an egg with a sledge hammer.

```js
var item = '[email_image,id=1,c=member,fS=15,lH=20]';

var result = item.slice(1, -1).split(',').
    reduce(function (a,b) {
      var v=b.split('=');if(v.length===1) a.name=v[0];
      else a[v[0]]=v[1];return a}
,{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

I have modified your code this way.

```
var arr = str.slice(1, -1).split(','), arraytophp_test = {};
$.each(arr, function(key, value){
    if(value.indexOf('=') === -1){
       arraytophp_test.name = value;
    }else{
       var k = value.split('=')[0];
       var v = value.split('=')[1];
       arraytophp_test[k] = v;
    }
})
```

Where "str" is your string...

Comment: Thanks. but output looks like this now: {name: "[email_image", id: "1", c: "Member", fS: "15", lH: "20]"} brackets! i'd like to use the match regex. any idea?

Comment: console.log(arraytophp_test)
VM2642:1 Object {name: "email_image", id: "1", c: "member", fS: "15", lH: "20"}

Comment: Are you sure that output not this? If you tried it in console, dont forget to console.log your arraytophp_test in finish...

Comment: str is item. item = [email_image,id=1,c=member,fS=15,lH=20]